# Maximizing the $x$ value given a $y^2$ in equation

Tags: calculus

What $x$ value maximizes $y$ of the function $$y^2 + y + x^2 - 2x = 5$$

Answer is $1$.

OK so I try isolating $y$; so I can sum it up to zero and hopefully get something out of it.. and I get

$$y(y+1) = 5-2x-x^2$$

somehow the $y'$s don't cancel out. I know I am really missing a point here. I know for a fact that this is some sort of circle or parabola... but it doesn't help much either when i convert it into its standard equation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick way: derive the equation on $x$ (giving $2yy'+y'+2x-2=0$) and cancel $y'$. This gives $2x-2=0$.

---

The smart way: Complete the square:

$$y^2+y+\frac14=\left(y+\frac12\right)^2=\frac94-x^2+2x.$$

By monotonicity of $\left(y+\dfrac12\right)^2$ there is an extremum when $-2x+2=0$.

---

The hard way: Solve the quadratic equation for $y$ and maximize:

$$y=-\frac12\pm\frac12\sqrt{1-4(x^2-2x-5)}$$

$$0=\pm\frac14\frac{-4(2x-2)}{\sqrt{1-4(x^2-2x-5)}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

$y^2 + y + x^2 - 2x = 5$ represents a circle. Put in the right form, it would be like this:
$$y^2 + y + \frac14 + x^2 - 2x + 1= \frac{25}{4}$$
$$(y+\frac12)^2 + (x-1)^2 = \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2$$
So it means a circle of radius $2.5$ centered at $(1,-0.5)$.

Now you know which $x$ to choose.

Comment: Cool solution !